# Lucene Search in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco

I have a folder named as "12345" inside the document library of my site in Alfresco. Using Lucene search I want to to fetch all of my contents that reside in this folder.:

I have tried:

```
search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:"+siteName+"/cm:documentLibrary/cm:12345/*\"");

search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:"+siteName+"/cm:documentLibrary/*\" AND @cm\\:name:\""+entityID+"\"");

+PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes//* " AND +@cm\:name:"12345"
```

But using the above path does not go to the Specific Folder. How do I access the Folder inside a site?

Comment: Does any of these queries work?

Comment: Yes, what's the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your response mate, problem is resolved it was related to naming convention of folders in Alfresco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.
Any folder start with integer is Prefixed with the string "*x003" then after the First Integer you have to Concatenate "*"

So If folder name is "12345" it would be treated as _x0031_2345. And the Path will be "/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:sitename/cm:documentLibrary/cm:_x0031_2345"
I hope it helped.

Comment: This is ISO9075, for example, http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-iso9075Encode.html